# Take account Key pressed during Macro Execution

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling

I would like to push Excel to its limit by trying to make a car game.
The tricky part is when I try to move the car (so take account the key pressed by the user) during the game (when the macro is executed).

I have a screen that has to be refreshed faster and faster as the game goes (it simulates the road and the difficulty increased as time flies). Basically, it's just `Application.Wait (Now + delta_T)` inside a loop that decides what the road will be.

I rebinded key -> and <- with `Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", procedure:="GoLeft"` (same for right)

However when these keys are pushed during the execution of a main macro, "the procedures" are executed after the main macro... That's pretty inconvenient :/

Disclaimer : I'm aware that a lots of languages are more suitable for this. It's just my way of dealing with Covid19 ...

Thanks :)

Comment: VBA is single-threaded, so you cannot run a macro while another one is also running.

Comment: Try this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422427/excel-vba-onkey-macro-to-work-while-another-macro-is-running